# Raise a number to a power that varies in VHDL

Tags: vhdl

I have need to write a process that implement this correlation table :

E -> S

0 -> 2

1 -> 4

2 -> 8

3 -> 16

4 -> 32

5 -> 64

and so forth.

You can see clearly that the output can be easily calculated :

```
S = 1^(E+1)
```

However I'm not sure if it is possible to do this in VHDL with left shift. What bothers me is that we don't know in advance the size of (E+1) so we don't know how many 0 needs to be added so both sides of the equations have the same size.

Is there a smart way to do this in VHDL (smarter than to do a MUX) ?

Comment: much is possible in VHDL. But what do you want: just a simulation, or synthesizable code? And if the latter, what clock frequency doe you want to run? The problem is actually not difficult, but the output is variable in length (i.e. number of bits).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few different ways to achieve this (for the purpose of synthesis); I'm sure there are more than those listed here. If `E` is an input generic to your module (which it doesn't sound like it is, otherwise you would know what `E+1` is in advance), no "additional" logic is required.

If `E` is an input to the module, but you have an upper bound on E, you could simply use a ROM as a lookup (This isn't an efficient use of memory, but will work). Alternatively, you could use a function that takes `E` as an input and returns a vector that represents the result, `S` (Note that this also requires `E` being bounded, which bounds the size of the result).

```
constant MAX_WID : natural := 64;
...

-- You can use unsigned in place of slv, if that is more suitable
function calc_s(e : integer) return std_logic_vector is
    -- MAX_WID is effectively your maximum value of E
    variable ret : std_logic_vector(MAX_WID+1 downto 0) := (others => '0');
begin
    ret(e+1) := '1';
    return ret;
end calc_s;
```

Comment: It works, but how does "(MAX_WID+1 downto 0)" is synthethized? How does the synthetizer know how long the bus is if it varies?

Comment: It doesn't; MAX_WID is a constant that represents the upper bound on your input, E.

Comment: Yes, this is also a possibility ;) Apparently the best one ;P

Answer (score 1):

This is possible in many ways. E.g.
To start:

```
use ieee.math_real.all;

constant E : natural := 0; -- any value >= 0
constant S : integer := natural(2 ** real(E+1));
```

Or

```
use ieee.numeric_std.all;
....
constant E : natural := 0;
constant S : unsigned((E+1) downto 0):= (
    (E+1) => '1',
    others => '0');
```

Or

```
use ieee.math_real.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;
....
constant E : natural := 0;
constant S : unsigned((E+1) downto 0) :=
    to_unsigned(integer(2 ** real(E+1)), E+2));
```

Or

```
use ieee.numeric_std.all;
....
constant E : natural := 0;
signal S : unsigned((E+1) downto 0);
....
S <= left_shift(to_unsigned(1, (E+2)), E+1);
```

Etc, etc.

I mean, what would you like to achieve?